# BERT training error - forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: pytorch, nlp, torch, bert-language-model

I'm trying to train Bert for question answering using squad. At the end I wanna use Labse for this and train it again on other language and see the score growth. As I train bert I immediately get this error:
`forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'`

To be honest I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Maybe some of you can help me. I am using squad v 1.0 dataset

```
from datasets import load_dataset
raw_datasets = load_dataset("squad", split='train')


from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertModel
from transformers import AutoTokenizer


model_checkpoint = "setu4993/LaBSE"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)



max_length = 384
stride = 128


def preprocess_training_examples(examples):
    questions = [q.strip() for q in examples["question"]]
    inputs = tokenizer(
        questions,
        examples["context"],
        max_length=max_length,
        truncation="only_second",
        stride=stride,
        return_overflowing_tokens=True,
        return_offsets_mapping=True,
        padding="max_length",
    )

    offset_mapping = inputs.pop("offset_mapping")
    sample_map = inputs.pop("overflow_to_sample_mapping")
    answers = examples["answers"]
    start_positions = []
    end_positions = []

    for i, offset in enumerate(offset_mapping):
        sample_idx = sample_map[i]
        answer = answers[sample_idx]
        start_char = answer["answer_start"][0]
        end_char = answer["answer_start"][0] + len(answer["text"][0])
        sequence_ids = inputs.sequence_ids(i)

        # Find the start and end of the context
        idx = 0
        while sequence_ids[idx] != 1:
            idx += 1
        context_start = idx
        while sequence_ids[idx] == 1:
            idx += 1
        context_end = idx - 1

        # If the answer is not fully inside the context, label is (0, 0)
        if offset[context_start][0] > start_char or offset[context_end][1] < end_char:
            start_positions.append(0)
            end_positions.append(0)
        else:
            # Otherwise it's the start and end token positions
            idx = context_start
            while idx <= context_end and offset[idx][0] <= start_char:
                idx += 1
            start_positions.append(idx - 1)

            idx = context_end
            while idx >= context_start and offset[idx][1] >= end_char:
                idx -= 1
            end_positions.append(idx + 1)

    inputs["start_positions"] = start_positions
    inputs["end_positions"] = end_positions
    return inputs


train_dataset = raw_datasets.map(
    preprocess_training_examples,
    batched=True,
    remove_columns=raw_datasets.column_names,
)
len(raw_datasets), len(train_dataset)

from transformers import TrainingArguments

args = TrainingArguments(
    "bert-finetuned-squad",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
)

from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer)


from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
trainer.train()


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-2920a50b14d4> in <module>()
     10     tokenizer=tokenizer,
     11 )
---> 12 trainer.train()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

Comment: You might want to try: `BertLMHeadModel`.
Probably that's the model you are looking for. The one you're using currently, only returns "naked" hidden states. It does not have a *head*, which maps hidden representation to tokens. -> Hence there is no `labels` argument.

Comment: @Mateusz how did to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i suggest you change the import to `BertForSequenceClassification`

I suggest you check this out in the [docs](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.21.1/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1510) the trainer class actually looks for this specific argument in the forward pass "labels"; which is not stated quite clearly in the huggingface docs

```py
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
```

Comment: Or whatever problem you're trying to work on

Comment: As far as I understand, he is trying to use the model directly as it is, without adding layers to it. It would be better to use BertForQuestionAnswering if he is going to continue using it this way. But since BertForQuestionAnswering's forward method does not accept labels variable, he will have to write the loss function by himself.
source: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.TFBertForQuestionAnswering

Comment: correct sorry did not see what labels he's using thanks for helping me clarify